# Wireless connection error

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

error 105 (net::err_name_not_resolved): The server could not be found.

I am trying to understand and debug the above error.  I am able to connect to wireless from my ubuntu, but not able to browse.  I am using chrome.  It works on windows though.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When does this error occur?

Comment: when I am trying to access any website

Comment: Within chrome? You tried another browser?

Comment: tried FF now, it simply says server not found.

But my wireless is connected, it says active

Comment: Seems like DNS resolution is failing.

Comment: Try pinging, say, 8.8.8.8 (Google Public DNS). If you can get a ping from there, that would indeed point to DNS problems, in which case you'd want to switch DNS servers in Ubuntu or figure out why its not working with your ISPs servers (if that's what you're using in Windows). Here's a list of free public DNS servers if you need it: http://theos.in/windows-xp/free-fast-public-dns-server-list/

Answer (score 0):

Normally the answer to this is to reinstall the browser.

This error indicated that your web browser is unable to do a DNS lookup on the website you are trying to connect to.

If you are able to connect to the internet with another browser, reinstall chrome.

If you are not able to connect, check your IP settings in Ubuntu and make sure you have DNS servers assigned (IFCONFIG will do it)

If your DNS settings are ok, its going to be a problem with yoru internet connection.  I've also seen one case a long time (a couple of months) ago where reinstalling NIC (WiFi or Ethernet) drivers sorted this problem out on a different browser... always worth a shot.